# Is it safe to compare equality of Date.now in a one line statement

Tags: swift, date

I am trying to write a line that evaluates to a bool that says whether an optional Date object is in the future or not.

I wrote the following statement

```
let dateIsInFuture = (optionalDate ?? .now) >= .now
```

And I am curious if this is bad form. Especially since if the first and second .now are evaluated at different times they may cease to be equal. Of course I can pull out now into a different line to remove this ambiguity... but I am curious if this would work with the way swift compiles and runs this line of code.

Comment: You're using `>=` which just presumes the order in which they're computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than defaulting to `.now`, default to either `.distantFuture` or `.distantPast` in order to be clear about what you intend to happen in the nil case. Based on your use of `>=`, I assume you mean this:

```
let dateIsInFuture = (optionalDate ?? .distantFuture) >= .now
```

This would also be a good time to decide whether you could make `optionalDate` non-Optional, by defaulting it to `.distantFuture` earlier. Then you can avoid a lot of `??` and `if let` code.

Answer (score 3):

Those two calls will have (ever so *slightly*) different times, yes. It's unlikely to matter in practice though.

Consider using [`Optional.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/map(_:)):

```
let dateIsInFuture = optionalDate.map { $0 >= .now } ?? true
```